# Getting started with d3.js, what files are needed?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I am trying to get start with *d3.js* and have downloaded the latest release from https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/releases. Other than the *d3.js* file, there are a lot of other scripts in the **src** and **spec** folders.

Do we need to put all these into our own project directory? Or it is enough to copy the *d3.js* file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be confusing dc.js and d3.js?

dc.js is a charting library built on top of d3.js and crossfilter. D3 is a powerful but low level graphics library, and crossfilter is a simple, fast client-side database.

As such, to run dc.js you need

- d3.js
- crossfilter.js
- dc.js
- dc.css

Most users don’t check out the GitHub repo. That’s mostly for developers.

As with most JavaScript libraries, most users will create a `package.json` for npm. Depending on `dc` and then running `npm install` will pull in D3 and crossfilter (actually crossfilter2, the community fork with some improvements).

Alternately you could pull in all of the above directly from CDNs into your web page, and not bother with npm at all. Instructions are in the README.

It all depends how you want to deploy your app.